# Creating plugin for changing slug

Tags: plugins, slug

I need help about creating plugin for rewriting slug. When you enter you post name or page name wordpress is creating slug. So I want to make some modification. I don't know how to make changes in DB and also to write some php code. Please help me about where to start and what to see or learn some tut.

Idea is If you enter - Hello Wordpress - to have
example not real scenario : hheelloo-wwoorrddppress

Comment: Please Google or search on this site. Then try to write some code, then someone can help you here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the slug as you want in wordpress.

Just go to the post or to the page. Edit the Post or the Page you want to change the slug. On the right side there is a button: Screen Options. Click it and Check slug. Then you'll manually can give what ever slug you want for the post or page.

Comment: But I want to make that automatic.